# subtract two "lists of dictionaries"

Tags: dictionary, python-2.7, unique, union, intersect

How should I subtract two `list of dictionaries` in a pythonic way?

*I want to find the element that are unique in the first listOfDict.*

See my example below:

```
firstDict = [{'A':1 ,'B':1}, {'A':2 ,'B':2}]
secondDict = [{'A':3 ,'B':3}, {'A':2 ,'B':2}]
```

`magicFunction(A, B)` should return

```
[{'A':1 ,'B':1}
```

and `magicFunction(B, A)` should return

```
[{'A':3 ,'B':3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sets for that, but a `dict` can not be added to a set unfortunately. You need to 'cast' the dictionaries to something that a set *can* handle, e.g. a immutable type such as a sequence of tuples. Combine that with an index to return the referenced `dict`:

```
def magicFunction(a, b):
    a = [tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in a]
    b = [tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in b]
    return [dict(kvs) for kvs in set(a).difference(b)]
```

Result:

```
>>> firstDict = [{'A':1 ,'B':1}, {'A':2 ,'B':2}]
>>> secondDict = [{'A':3 ,'B':3}, {'A':2 ,'B':2}]
>>> magicFunction(firstDict, secondDict)
[{'A': 1, 'B': 1}]
>>> magicFunction(secondDict, firstDict)
[{'A': 3, 'B': 3}]
```

Comment: This is  great, but I have dictionaries inside these dictionaries....any idea how I  might go about that?

Comment: @aNxello: You'll have to use a recursive version of `magicFunction`, I'm afraid. Or re-think your data structures.